# Python - Mapping a 2d array to a grid with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, grid, mapping

I'm new to pyplot and haven't been able to find a proper solution to map an array to a coloured grid. For example, if I have a 10x10 2d array and 10x10 grid:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]]
```

If 0s and 1s are blues and reds respectively then the grid should look like this:

[image: colored grid (I didn't generate this image)]

How can I do this with pyplot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`imshow`** [matplotlib-doc]](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib-pyplot-imshow) for this:

```
data = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0],
    [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

So you just pass the 2d-list to `imshow()`, and this will generate the following image:

[image: result of imshow]

As specified in the documentation, you can use another colormap to use other colors for `0` and `1`, for example:

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
```

will yield the same data, but with a blue-white-red colormap:

[image: result of imshow blue-red]

Answer (score 8):

The appropriate function you need is [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#pcolor-demo):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['Blue','red'])
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.pcolor(data[::-1],cmap=cmap,edgecolors='k', linewidths=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or:

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['Blue','red'])
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.pcolor(data[::-1],cmap=cmap,edgecolors='k', linewidths=3)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5,step=1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5,step=1))
plt.show()
```

[image]